# Describe recursive grammar with type aliases

Tags: scala, recursive-datastructures, recursive-descent, type-alias, fastparse

How can I describe this recursive grammar with type aliases:

```
type FieldValue = Seq[String] :+: String :+: Int :+: Long :+: CNil
type FieldLeaf = FieldValue :+: SubField :+: CNil
type SubField = Seq[Field]
type Field = (String, FieldLeaf)
```

As it stands, the Scala compiler (2.12.1) gives me:

```
Error:(14, 25) illegal cyclic reference involving type FieldLeaf
  type Field = (String, FieldLeaf)
```

PS the context of this is parsing a recursive grammar with [fastparse](https://github.com/lihaoyi/fastparse).

---

**Edit (in response to @OlivierBlanvillain's answer below)**

That answer was really a thing of beauty and exactly what I was looking for, I'll remember it for the future.

However, for other reasons, in this particular case I had to go with these definitions instead:

```
  case class Field(name: String, leaf: FieldLeaf)
  sealed trait FieldLeaf
  sealed trait FieldValue extends FieldLeaf
  case class StringsFieldValue(value: Seq[String]) extends FieldValue
  case class StringFieldValue(value: String) extends FieldValue
  case class IntFieldValue(value: Int) extends FieldValue
  case class LongFieldValue(value: Long) extends FieldValue
  case class SubField(value: Seq[Field]) extends FieldLeaf
```

---

See also:
[Instantiate types from recursive type grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573747/instantiate-types-from-recursive-type-grammar)

Comment: What is `CNil` and `:+:`?

Comment: Also, maybe you could explain what structure it should have, maybe it is design fault. 
Getting rid of `type Subfield` and using `Seq[Field]` should resolve your problem, but maybe there is better solution eg, creating additional classes.

Comment: Sorry @Rumid, should have included the imports. I excluded them for brevity. It's Shapeless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a fix point type. For example:

```
case class Fix[F[_]](out: F[Fix[F]])
```

Lets you write:

```
type FieldValue = Seq[String] :+: String :+: Int :+: Long :+: CNil
type FieldLeaf[F] = FieldValue :+: SubField[F] :+: CNil
type SubField[F] = Seq[F]
type Field0[F] = (String, FieldLeaf[F])

type Field = Fix[Field0]
```