# Instantiate types from recursive type grammar

Tags: scala, shapeless, recursive-datastructures, circe

Given this recursive type grammar:

```
case class Fix[F[_]](out: F[Fix[F]])
type FieldValue = Seq[String] :+: String :+: Int :+: Long :+: CNil
type FieldLeaf[F] = FieldValue :+: SubField[F] :+: CNil
type SubField[F] = Seq[F]
type Field0[F] = (String, FieldLeaf[F])
type Field = Fix[Field0]
```

And instances of `Seq[Field]`

**Is it feasible to instantiate concrete classes from the type grammar?**

I.e:

```
def instantiate[T](fields:Seq[Field]):Option[T] = ....
case class Person(id:Long, name:String)
val fields:Seq[Field] = .... //seq of person fields
val person:Option[Person] = instantiate[Person](fields)
```

I imagine [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) could be used for this, like in the json-library [Circe](https://github.com/circe/circe).

---

See also [Describe recursive grammar with type aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42548402/describe-recursive-grammar-with-type-aliases)

Comment: What do you mean by instantiate concrete classes? What is `T` in your function?

Comment: @OlivierBlanvillain see update.

Comment: Reply from the Shapeless gitter channel: You can do that with a mix of ToHList, Typeable and Generic. Yielding an Option[Person] of course.

Comment: Ended up recursively mapping everything to equivalent Circe Json constructs, because json is actually a pretty good representation of recursive data, and Circe has great support for decoding json to case classes and sealed traits.